# Uber API - Driver

Tags: uber-api

Does the Uber API currently allow a "driver" to login and then determine if the driver has a current request that is "in_progress". My app needs to verify in real-time if the API authenticated driver (via OAuth) is currently driving passengers. It seems like most of the API is from a "rider" standpoint as opposed to a driver.

Answer (score 3):

I think there is no API currently for driver side, only rider clients can make requests to Uber endpoints now.